# How to calculate the roots of $z^{N} + 1 = 0$?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

My book says that the result should be $e^{j2\pi k/N}$ with $k = 1,2,...,N$ but to me the results looks much more like this:

Since the absolute value of the solution must be 1

$e^{j\omega N} = -1$

$\cos(\omega N) + j\sin(\omega N) = -1$

then

$\omega N = \pi + 2\pi k$

therefore:

$\omega = \frac{\pi}{N} + \frac{2\pi}{N} k$

$k = 0,1,...,N-1$

what am I missing?

Furthermore, if the equation were $z^{-N} - 1 = 0$ the result would still be the same in my opionion, due to the fact that cosine is an even function.

Comment: `then ωN=π` That should rather be $\,\omega N = \pi \color{red}{+2k\pi}\,$.

Comment: @dxiv yes but it doesn't explain why it is different from the solution of the book...

Comment: $\left(e^{j2\pi k/N}\right)^N=e^{j2\pi k}=1 \ne -1$ so your book made a mistake.

Comment: Are you sure the book is not talking about $z^N = 1$, or $z^n - 1 = 0$? Otherwise it's really a mistake.

Comment: Try to approach with group theory this question. It is so fun :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book is clearly wrong: if you take $k=N$, you get $e^{2\pi j}=1$, which is not a root.

Your solution is correct. The $N^{\rm th}$ roots of $-1$ are
$$
z=e^{j(\pi/N+2k\pi/N)}, \ \ \ \ k=0,1,\ldots,N-1. 
$$
As for your last comment, since $(-1)^{-1}=-1$, the roots are the same: $z^N=-1$ is the same equation as $1/z^N=1/(-1).$